# Election questions

Tags: support, election

1. I wanted to do some copy-editing of https://academia.stackexchange.com/election but there is no "edit" button.  How was the text generated?  How may I contribute with some minimal copy editing?
2. We already have four moderators.  Did Academia grow?  Did it become a more boisterous community?  Did some of our moderators' availability change?  In other words, what triggered this election?  (I already read https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99515/287826.)

Answer (score 5):

1. It looks like it is editable by mods. If there are edits you want, I suggest starting a new question with one clearly explained edit per answer. After a brief period for others to chime in and/or mods to reach a consensus, we can make the edits.
2. The election was triggered by us in a private chat room when I asked *do we want another mod*, to which the rest responded, *probably wouldn't hurt*. We then asked the SE team and they said sure. This was not the first time we asked ourselves about our moderating load, but it was the first time we all thought it was reasonable to bring someone else in. In answer to the other questions: Yes we have grown. There is a little more mod work. I wouldn't say there is a huge change in our availability, but less spare capacity to cover when other mods are busy.

I think the key thing is the current mods are all still very committed to our community and not going anywhere. We just wanted another hand to help out.

Comment: The site continues to grow over time. There is definitely more work than we had a year ago.